# Copying 6GB file with scp finishes at 1.8GB

Tags: windows, ubuntu, scp

```
G:\>ssh phrogz@phrogz.net

phrogz@nematode:~$ cd /backup/
phrogz@nematode:/backup$ la
total 6057228
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root       4096 2011-04-21 10:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root   root       4096 2011-03-08 10:43 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 phrogz root 6196527104 2011-04-21 10:48 nematode.tar.gz

phrogz@nematode:/backup$ logout
Connection to phrogz.net closed.

G:\>scp phrogz@phrogz.net:/backup/nematode.tar.gz .
nematode.tar.gz                                  100% 1813MB 328.3KB/s 1:34:17
8YEv_◄OuA*→♠x!'!♠"1)xza↨s¿ç*?ê%A⌂YDU~)÷♀↓¿Ixw.ö%k►ò¬IX"òV"♥òO→◄¼

G:\>which scp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\scp.EXE
```

1. Why does SCP incorrectly think that the file is only 1.8GB?
2. How can I fix this and properly copy this full file using SCP?

Comment: Workaround: using the GUI [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php), despite the terrifying web page, appears to be on track to download the full file.

Comment: “on track” - did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that the 32 bit version has a ~2GB file size ceiling. Try a 64 bit build.